# Loss of data when copying a file

Tags: file

```
int32_t a[MAX];
int main()
{

    FILE *f = fopen("New.doc","rb");
    FILE *g = fopen("temp.doc","wb");
    if (f == NULL || g == NULL)
        return 0;
    int n;
    while ((n = fread(a, 4, MAX, f)) > 0)
        fwrite(a, 1, n, g);
    fclose(f);
    fclose(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Size on disk of "new.doc" in my computer is 20kb, when I ran the code above, I got "temp.doc" with 5kb in size => loss of data. However, when I changed 4 into 1, I got "temp.doc" which is exactly similar to "new.doc". Can anyone explain what happened? Thank you.

Comment: Check the return value from `fwrite`.  Always.  And consider using meaningful variable names--this isn't Fortran.

Comment: int32_t is a standard 4-bytes integer in library <stdint> in c++. When I checked value from fread, it just read 5kb, exactly what was written on destination file, temp.doc.

Comment: But, the same thing happened when I changed it to int :(. And by the way, I use compiler for c++, so I think it is ok.

Comment: removed the unrelated [tag:c++] tag. If you really wanted to ask "How to copy a file in C++", then the search box was your area

Answer (score 1):

```
fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

> On success, **fread()** and **fwrite()** return the number of items read or
>   written. *This number equals the number of* **bytes** *transferred only when
>   size is* **1**.

In your case

```
n = fread(a, 4, MAX, f)
```

would return `sizeof file/4`. When you write again, you actually write `1/4` of the file. You can fix the `fread` call to have size `1` instead of `4`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you did not pay attention to the semantics of `fread()` and `fwrite()`.  One returns the number of items written, the other requires the number of bytes to write.  In your case, you are reading 4-byte elements and writing 1-byte elements, so of course you are missing 75% of your file.  Use a matching element size in the calls to `fread()` and `fwrite()` and all will be well.

Note that if your files do not actually contain 4-byte elements (e.g. they are text files), you better use an element size of 1 (and I suggest changing `a` to be of type `char` to be less confusing, and using `sizeof(a[0])` as the element size in the function calls).

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much for showing my stupid mistake :(.